# pulp: why the message of model is optimal, but the value of variable are not satisfy constraint conditions

Tags: python, constraints, pulp

pulp version: 2.3

My model used PULP_CBC_CMD to solve. The status of return is 1 and the message of reture is Optimal. But, the value of variable are not satisfy constraint conditions which I set. I also use GLPK to sovle, the problem is the same. I don't konw why and what should I do ?
The simple example is following, which is to illustrate the problem visually. Note that our model is more complex than this example.

e.g.
there are four variable,a,b,c,d, which are all range [0,1], and one of more constraint coditions is a+b=c+d. The result of model solve are a=0.122, b=0.345, c=0.222, d=0.233. But a+b!=c+d.

```
model.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=False))
# model.solve(GLPK(msg=False))
status, message = model.status, LpStatus[model.status]
# the reture of model are status=1 message=optimal
```

I used another solver GLPK to sovle
I expect that the result of model solve a, b, c, d can satisfy the constraint codition  a+b!=c+d.

Comment: Show your code for an MCVE or this is not reproducible. We can trivially show a problem definition that will satisfy your constraint and it will not solve your actual problem.